# How to override specific methods in a TypeScript class?

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I'm generally finding TS highly confusing. I'm often wanting to extend/merge existing declarations or override some parts of them, but I don't know how.

For instance, I'm wondering how to change the types of the `t` method:

```
declare class VueI18n {
  constructor(options?: VueI18n.I18nOptions)

  readonly messages: VueI18n.LocaleMessages;
  readonly dateTimeFormats: VueI18n.DateTimeFormats;
  readonly numberFormats: VueI18n.NumberFormats;

  locale: VueI18n.Locale;
  fallbackLocale: VueI18n.Locale;
  missing: VueI18n.MissingHandler;
  formatter: VueI18n.Formatter;
  silentTranslationWarn: boolean;

  t(key: VueI18n.Path, values?: VueI18n.Values): VueI18n.TranslateResult;
  t(key: VueI18n.Path, locale: VueI18n.Locale, values?: VueI18n.Values): VueI18n.TranslateResult;

  // ...
```

I want to change it so it returns a string, not a `VueI18n.TranslateResult`. This type is being imported from a package (vue-i18n), so I'd like to override it in my own code somehow.

Comment: Does `VueI18N.TranslateResult` extend `string`?

Comment: I don't know if I got it right, why would you override the method? You can use it inside you own method, take the result transform and in your method return your string. You don't need to actually override the class method and lost the logic there implemented

Comment: `TranslateResult` can be a string or an object, which is causing warnings in my code where a string is expected. I have to do `this.$t(...) as string` everywhere. I'd rather just override it and force `t` to return a string.

Comment: It suppose to work since type TranslateResult = string | LocaleMessages;

Comment: You would think so, but no. Try defining a type like `string | SomeInterface` and then passing a variable of that type toa function that accepts only a string. You'll get a type error.